# Where are the tomcat Launch & Paths panels in Luna?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I was given some set up instructions for a Java project that uses Tomcat.  I currently work on a Java app that uses Tomcat and I can can run it via Eclipse.

This new app refers to a couple panels that I can't find.   Specifically, Launch & Paths.  I'm assuming the screen shot below is from an older eclipse version?  Where are the equivalent panels in Luna?

[image: Where is this in Luna?]

Comment: That screen shot is from the My Eclipse product, which is a customized, "enhanced" Eclipse-based product. Can you add to the question the specific instructions that you're trying to reproduce in vanilla Eclipse?

Comment: you have that in Servers view. Take a look on http://crunchify.com/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-and-install-apache-tomcat-server-in-eclipse-development-environment-ide/.